# Mapping person and employee in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, automapping

How can I map following queries using Fluent NHibernate (entity, mapping class etc..),  the employee ids are stored in identifier tables. Person table contains employee information and non-employee information.

SELECT p.Id, p.FirstName, p.LastName

```
 FROM Person p
```

UNION ALL

```
SELECT e.Id, e.FirstName, e.LastName 

  FROM Employee e
```

INNER JOIN identifier i on (e.Id = i.value)

INNER JOIN type t on (i.typeid = t.id and i.typeName = 'EmployeeId')

Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a union strategy for mapping your subclasses. Have a read of the [subclassing](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#Subclasses) section of the Fluent NHibernate wiki, but instead of calling `DiscriminateSubclassesOnColumn` in your `ClassMap` you'd call `UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping`.

What you'd end up with is a `ClassMap` for your base-class, then a `SubclassMap` for each of your subclasses; the `ClassMap` would have a call to `UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping` in it's constructor.

Something like this:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
  public PersonMap()
  {
     // ... mappings ...
     UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();
  }
}

public class EmployeeMap : SubclassMap<Employee>
{
  public EmployeeMap()
  {
    // ... mappings ...
  }
}
```

Comment: James, Big fan of yours. Thank you so much!!.

Comment: Is this possible to achieve with automapping (conventions + overrides)?